# What difference is there between customising an optimizer or not in Keras

Tags: keras

My question is basically what is the difference in Keras if I do

```
# first method

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

or simply

```
# second method 

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Both compile well, but when I do

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=4)
```

the first one leads to

```
ValueError: Tensor("training/SGD/Variable:0", shape=(11, 11, 4, 96), 
dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("SGD/momentum/read:0", 
shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

while the second method, where I use the default 'sgd' optimizer, the network trains normally.

The error seems to suggest that 2 tensors are not from the same graph, but I guess is something that has to do with the imported SGD?

I also tried the first method on a different model I have and surprisingly it does not lead to error. I think it should not be model-architecture dependant.

Why does this happen?

Keras version: 2.2.4
Python version: 3.6.5
TensorFlow version: 1.13.1

**EDIT**

My bad, I had a

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as test:
  ...
```

in the middle of my code

Comment: What version of tensorflow and python do you have installed?

Comment: Please include self-containing examples, not just snippets that we cannot execute

Comment: Sounds like a buggy keras version, an incompatibility between tf version and keras version, or something like that.

Comment: Sorry my bad, in creating a self-contained example I realised what was the problem, in my case, I was testing in the middle to check some things with `tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as test:
  ...` So that must have created another graph.  

Error solved, so I guess there is no difference between the 2 methods I mentioned?

Comment: Yeah there shouldn't be any difference